# What is the use of square brackets in the name attribute?

Tags: html

What is the use of square brackets in this example? And when it is needed.`<input type="text" name="name[]">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The submitted data will be an array, rather than a scalar value.

Comment: what is scalar value? can you give me an example?

Comment: `"abc"`, `2`, `3.14`, `true`, etc. are scalars. `["abc"]`, to give one example, is an array.

Comment: @ErrolPaleracio accepting the answer was all you needed to do. The idea is that the question stays here in case anyone else has the same question.